# how to transfer data from a second page to a third page from the button click in mainpage

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, uwp

I'm trying to create an app that will have a  *main page* that has 2 buttons.

1. the first button opens a popup page that has 2 pickers and the user has to select some value and when done, return to the main page.
2. the second button on the main page opens a content page that has 2 labels that are supposed to receive data from the popup page. So it's supposed to be like a final report page.
   I would appreciate It if someone could provide me with a simple code preferable using MVVM. I have already created a similar app but having the main page as a MasterDetailPage and it works perfectly, the only issue I have now is, I would like to have the main page as a content page instead of masterdetailpage. I hope what I wrote is understandable

mainpage xaml

```
  <Button x:Name="board" Clicked="board_Clicked" Text="board Setup" />
<Button x:Name="lblFinalPage" Clicked="lblFinalPage_Clicked" Text="FinalPage" />
```

Second page

```
<Picker SelectedItem="{Binding PICKER1}" WidthRequest="120" FontSize="10" TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke">
                            <Picker.Items>
                                <x:String>15 cm</x:String>
                                <x:String>30 cm</x:String>
                                <x:String>45 cm</x:String>
                                <x:String>60 cm</x:String>
                                <
                            </Picker.Items>
                  </Picker>
                    

 <Picker  SelectedItem="{Binding PICKER2}" WidthRequest="120" FontSize="10" TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke">
                            <Picker.Items>
                                <x:String>Supine</x:String>
                                <x:String>Fst</x:String>
                            </Picker.Items>
                        </Picker>
```

third page

```
 <Label Text="{Binding piCKER1}"></Label>
<Label Text="{Binding piCKER2}" ></Label>
```

secondview

```
 public secondview()
     {
         SaveCommand = new Xamarin.Forms.Command(HandleAction);

     }

     async void HandleAction(object obj)
     {
         await ((App5.App)App.Current).MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(
         new finalPage()
         {
             BindingContext = new finalpageViewModel(PICKER1)
             
         });

     }
     string picker1;
     public string PICKER1
     {
         get
         {
             return picker1;
         }
         set
         {
             if (value != picker1)
             {
                 picker1 = value;
                 PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(PICKER1)));
             }
         }
     }


     public ICommand SaveCommand
     {
         get;
         set;
     }

     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
 }
```

finalpage

```
   public finalpageViewModel(string pICKER1)
    {
        piCKER1 = pICKER1;
    }
    public string piCKER1
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

the issue I have with this here is, it only works if I have the button in the second page then I am able to pass the data to the final page,
but I would want the user to return to the mainpage and perform other stuff and click on the other button and navigate to the final page

Comment: the simplest approach would be to have all three pages share the same VM instance

Answer (score 1):

You can create a **DataModel** model class to store the string data and it can be used to pass to the third page .

```
public class DataModel
{
    public string PICKER1 { set; get; }
    public string PICKER2 { set; get; }

    public DataModel()
    {

    }
}
```

Then in **MainPage** , binding this data model and just passing **MainPage**'s `BindingContext` to second page or third page .

```
public partial class PageMain : ContentPage
{
    public DataModel dataModel;
    public PageMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataModel = new DataModel();
        BindingContext = dataModel;
    }

    private void Button_Clicked_Second(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Navigation.PushAsync(new PageSecond(BindingContext));
    }

    private void Button_Clicked_Third(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Navigation.PushAsync(new PageFinal(BindingContext));
    }

}
```

**SecondPage** need to bind the passed `BindingContext`:

```
public partial class PageSecond : ContentPage
{
    public PageSecond(object bindingContext)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = bindingContext;
    }
}
```

ThirdPage also need to bind the passed `BindingContext`:

```
public partial class PageFinal : ContentPage
{
    public PageFinal(object bindingContext)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = bindingContext;
    }
}
```

The **Xaml** code of **MainPage** and **SecondPage** not need to be modified.However, the **ThirdPage** need to modify its binding name of `Label` text to keep the same with the `DataModel`:

```
<Label Text="{Binding PICKER1}"></Label>
<Label Text="{Binding PICKER2}" ></Label>
```

Now we can see the effect:

[image]